# Auto close youtube video on colorbox pop up close

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox pop up having youtube video, but it does not close when youtube video ends.

Colorbox should automatically close at video ends.

Comment: Add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: Can you please provide a code example in your question description.

Answer (score 0):

For auto close you have to trap the YouTube video state. This state can interact with color box close event.

YouTube video state can be checked using YouTube API. Just visit the API at -

[YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

Available video states are - 
unstarted=-1, ended=0, playing=1, paused=2, buffering=3, video cued=5

Getting video state one can hybridised the color box close event - parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()

Visit the full implementation of Colorbox close event and YouTube video API at [INFOTOKRI](http://www.infotokri.in/2013/09/close-colorbox-automatically-when.html) with a sample demo.